# Maven clean package : repo looking in wrong directory

Tags: java, maven, build, war

If i clean my project through eclipse and the use Maven command `mvn package` through the command line to build WAR file everything works fine.

But if i use the command `mvn clean package` i am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] bad path element "C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.
1\xml-apis.jar": no such file or directory
```

**EDIT**

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on
 project merlinv2: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation fail
ure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompiler
Mojo.java:729)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:208)
        ... 19 more
```

I have `xml-apis.jar` specified in my `pom.xml` as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

This creates the jar file in this directory : `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01`. I know the `xalan\serializer\2.7.1` jar is a dependency of `xml-apis` but i do not know why Maven is looking in `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\xml-apis.jar` directory for this when it is not in this directory and eclipse works fine

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: This `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\xml-apis.jar` could be dependency for some other jar file..Delete this folder manually from `.m2` directory and then try again command like `mvn clean package -U`

Comment: Maybe, maven cache is in an invalid state. I would try to delete everything in `.m2\repository\`, run `mvn clean` and afterwards test if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Try mvn dependecy:tree to see what dependency requires the 2.7.1 version

Comment: I will not suggest to delete everything from the `respository` it will take lots of time if all comes from `maven` or any other place

Comment: even if i deleted the repository the same folder structure is built but i am getting the same issue. I have also tried using `mvn clean package -U` but this was the same

Comment: First would it be helpful having the full logging output and not only excerpts...

Comment: i have added in the very end of the error log but the rest of the error logging does not show any relevant information